# Success page should not open directly, but only when the form is filled - Redirecting in PHP

Tags: php, header

I have a headers statement which redirects after a form is filled. So my form is on form.php and then if it is filled in it redirects to a success page "success.php". I want the success page to open only if come through via the form and not if it type www.domain.com/success.php directly in the browser. How may I achieve this? Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: Try using sessions. Store a variable that the form was filled and if it is not set on success.php, redirect back to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the POST variable is set that is for the submit button. E.g.,

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Then in PHP code on success.php:

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['Submit']) ) {
    die();
}
```

This die()s but you could have it show a different response or have it redirect to the form page (with header("Location: http://www.fadsf.com/form"))

Comment: Only problem with this is that he is doing a redirect to `success.php`. Meaning that the post variables will most likely not be set.

Comment: then check the post variable where you can (before redirect to success.php) and then do redirect instead as: success.php?okay=1. then change the success.php code to ($_GET['okay'] == 1) etc.

Comment: then the user only has to go to www.domain.com/success.php?okay=1 to circumvent the measure

Comment: if you really cared about security you could have a one-time use key that you use (instead of okay=1).

Comment: And where would you store that key for validation? Why even use a key?

Comment: db, or could be computable from current time and would expire after certain amount of time

Comment: if you stored in db, how would you know if the visitor is the same on the next page load. http is stateless so with the exception of the ip address, which could be the same for multiple visitors, you can't tell one user from another. The point is, in the end, you will have to use sessions "if you really care about security". And if using sessions, `$_SESSION['okay']=1;` would be just fine.

Comment: i mean if you stored a long key like 7dhfg78sgh789shdgf7sdfgdsfgh789hdf

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities I found here and there:

1. As Jonathan Kuhn proposed, try to use a session variable: set it before calling the page, and check it when loading it. If it's not set, you got an "intruder".
2. Use `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to check the IP of the user. If it is not the localhost IP (e.g. 127.0.0.1), you got an "unwanted visitor".
3. Put the PHP file outside of the web directory of your server so it cannot be accesed directly with a browser.

Comment: #2 doesn't really work. It is possible that someone other than localhost could hit the page. OP is just trying to stop people from accessing `success.php` without going to the form first. #3 would work, but instead of a redirect to `success.php`, you included the file.

Comment: I don't understand the problem about #2. Indeed: if someone other than localhost hits the page, then kick him out/show an error.

Comment: If you visited the website through the internet (not localhost), filled out the form correctly and get redirected to `success.php`. the remote addr would not be localhost, but you would still be a valid user and the page should load. If you however didn't fill out the form at all and just pulled up `success.php` directly, that is not valid.